# Alternative to adding a script tag after every AJAX element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I seem to have a problem with this but I'm not sure what it is.
I have a gallery with a list of links, every link brings a bunch of div elements asynchronously with the Jquery `load()` method.

**HTML**

```
      ...

     <section class="categories">
      <ul class="categoryList">
       <li class="selected HTML"> HTML & CSS </li>
       <li class="Javascript"> Javascript </li>
       <li class="JQuery"> JQuery </li>
       <li class="APIs"> APIs </li>
      </ul>
     </section><!--categories-->

  </div><!--leftColumn-->

  <div class="mainSection">
    <div class="wrapper">
    <h1 id="mainSectionTitle"> HTML & CSS </h1>
      <hr class="hr">


      <div class="gallery">
     <!-- Items are inserted here -->  

       </div><!--gallery-->
      </div><!--wrapper-->
     </div><!--mainSection-->

  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(".gallery").load("HTML-CSS.html");


  $(".categoryList li").click(function(){
    var text = $(this).text();
    $("#mainSectionTitle").addClass("animate-inLeft");
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
     $(".wrapper h1").text(text);
    setTimeout(timeOut, 700);
   });


 function timeOut(){
  $("#mainSectionTitle").removeClass("animate-inLeft")
 }

$(".thumb").mouseenter(function(){
   $(".opacityParagraph").addClass("opacityParagraphVisible")
    $(this).css("opacity", "0.1");
 })

    $(".thumb").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).css("opacity", "1");
$(".opacityParagraph").removeClass("opacityParagraphVisible")
  })


$(".Javascript").click(function(){

    $(".gallery").load("Javascript.html");

});
```

This is what's inside "Javascript.html", the element that gets called:

```
<div class="opacityLayer">  
     <p class="opacityParagraph">   </p>
   <div class="thumb"> <a href="..."> <img src="ProjectImages/HTML-CSS/flexbox-gallery.JPG"></a><p></p></div></div>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

In order for the mouse enter and mouse leave methods to work, I had to add a  tag at the end of every HTML section that I call and this creates some bugs. After a few calls or if I press the buttons too fast the elements start disappearing, etc.

Is there a better solution to this?

Comment: You could just delegate these events, right?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jose got it right... But he didn't explain anything to You.

When You define:

```
$('.thumb').on('mouseenter', ...
```

You are searching for all elements with `thumb` class which are currently in DOM tree, so you can attach an event listener to each of them (You attach as many listeners as there is `thumb` elements).

When You do:

```
$('.gallery').on('mouseenter','.thumb', ...
```

It means that You are searching for all elements with `gallery` class (I presume that there is just one element like that), and attaching an event listener to it(a single event listener). 
This event will fire when you will enter mouse on any `gallery` child element with `thumb` class.

This technique is called event delegation.

So... When You are adding more `thumb`'s to `gallery`, you don't have to add more listeners, because (like Jose pointed out) You have appended listener to the parent element which is in already in DOM.

What's more, You don't have to define two functions for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`

```
 $('.gallery').on('mouseenter','.thumb',toggleOpacity)
              .on('mouseleave','.thumb',toggleOpacity)


 function toggleOpacity() {
   $(".opacityParagraph").toggleClass("opacityParagraphVisible")
   $(this).toggleClass("thumbLowOpacity");
 }
```

You could go even further and cache `$('.opacityParagraph')` to variable, so Your script wouldn't search for those elements in DOM on each function call.

Comment: Thanks for the more in detail explanation, it works as expected now.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this

```
 $('.gallery').on('mouseenter','.thumb',function(){
    $(".opacityParagraph").addClass("opacityParagraphVisible")
    $(this).css("opacity", "0.1");
 })
```

and do the same for on mouseleave

Im assuming its because the objects you are adding are new to the dom tree so when you reference `.thum` directly its unknown.  Using `on` and reffering to a parent object that already exists usually does the trick.

Comment: Your anserw is correct, but you should also explain to him what you did there.

Comment: Hows my explanation @grzesiekgs.  I believe thats correct.

Comment: 'Using on and reffering to a parent object that already exists usually does the trick.' It doesn't explain what You did, and the 'usually' part is wrong.